# Mystery pipe under my sink and an intermittent sour smell

Tags: bathroom, bathroom-fixtures

First question, what is the black pipe in the picture above where the drain pipr goes into the wall?

Additionally, we have an intermittent sour smell coming from this bathroom.  I replaced the wax seal of the toilet thinking that might be the problem.  However it was not.  Last night, the smell occurred again.  After some investigation and wafting, i think I narrowed the smell to underneath the sink (hence the picture and post).

I guess the second question would be how do i get rid of the sour smell?

[image: https://imgur.com/gallery/RLDoQ]

Comment: What, you didn't like the answers you got at imgur?

Comment: Well, first, two different communities/audiences.  Second, I didn't expect to get answers, let alone useful ones, from imgur.  Last time I posted here, I posted pictures to imgur, and linked them here because I thought that's what I had to do.  Still new when it comes to posting with photo examples.

Comment: If it's a sewer gas smell then I'm guessing someone thought they could vent the drain into the sink cabinet. Is this bathroom original to the house or did someone add it? Is there an attic above this room where you can see if there's a vent that goes up?

Comment: @PlatinumGoose It is an added bathroom that was done as part of a garage conversion prior to my moving in.  I don't recall seeing anything in the attic/crawlspace resembling a pipe going up through the roof.  It was suggested that maybe the vent goes under the insulation and vents under the eve of the house.  I'm not sure if this is something that is done in practice of a one-story home.

Comment: No way to tell what it is thru the internet but i would put a check vent (air admittance valve) on it.  A one way vent that will allow it to draw air in but keep sewer gas from escaping into the room.

Comment: Is it threaded? Metal or plastic? I would cap it and see if the smell goes away. If your lav stops draining properly or starts stinking from it's drain, install a check vent on it as suggested by @Alaska man.

Comment: It is not threaded and it is plastic.  I put some plastic wrap over it with a rubber band.  We will see what happens.  The bathroom isnt used a lot, but when ghe smell happens it is noticable.  I may go to the hardware store and get a proper cap and see what happens.

Comment: I went to the local home depot and got a 90 degree elbow along with an air admittance valve.  Hopefully that will do the trick until we decide to remodel that bathroom.  Time will tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to have fixed this issue with a 90 degree elbow to fit over the pipe that comes out of the wall, and an Air Admittance Valve that I put on the other side of the elbow pipe.  No glue or tape was necessary.